# Does Intellij IDEA have methods (getters, setters or builder) prediction option?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, getter-setter, builder

Intellij IDEA is really great but I was really frustrated by the way IDEA predicts what method to call next when building some object with setters or builder.

For example we have simple object(powered by lombok):

```
@Value
@Builder
public class Benefit {

    private final long sourceUserId;
    private final BigDecimal baseValue;
    private final String multiplier;
    private final int bonusId;
    private final long bonusTtl;
    private final String benefitId;

}
```

But IDEA doesn't really care that I've already called it.
It would be great to see this method on the bottom of prediction list.
[image]

Is it obvious only for me that next one in the prediction should be `baseValue`?

I didn't find anything about it in google and here so maybe I've just missed some basic stuff?

Is there some way to change this prediction strategy?

Comment: Please follow the issue created for your bug report at YouTrack:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211080